# Help identifying a 1990's Panasonic(?) / Colnago(?) road/aero/speed bike from a German TV series

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

In 1992, "Freunde fürs Leben" (friends for life), a German TV series, began airing in which one of the protagonists, a doctor, was always carrying around his high-end luxury bike for fear of it being stolen. Unfortunately, I haven't been entirely successful in identifying which model it is, exactly.

Here's a rather good picture of the actor and the bike:

https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/nachrichtenfoto/serie-freunde-f%C3%BCrs-leben-stephan-schwartz-als-dr-nachrichtenfoto/179736106

The head tube should indicate that it's a Panasonic. However, every Panasonic from that era I could find had a rather orthodox geometry, with round tubes.

What I did find is the similarity with a Colnago C35.

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/87186942772857866/

Given the shared history of the Panasonic pro team and Colnago, it somehow makes sense. But there are some differences between the C35 and my bike in question.

Here is a clip with a good look at the bike:

Please tell me if you need additional angles; I'll have a look, then.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [bike in this post](http://www.kinkicycle.com/2015/05/carbon-panasonic.html).

[image]

> A stunning custom monocoque carbon Panasonic bike that was locked up outside the Bike Museum in Sakai, Osaka earlier this month...

[image]
According to translate the sticker says "kashiwabra grapes". Not sure what to make of that.

And [this catalog page](https://twitter.com/GAKUJIRA/status/806495805041360896/photo/4)
[image]

> (translated) Speaking of road racers at that time, Kuromori was still the main > player.
>
> Before Shimano's hand shifting was born.
> Dura's 74 series
> Campagnolo is a C record.
> The silver of the anodized aluminum was sparkling.
>
> Panasonic quickly commercialized a carbon monocoque frame and took it by surprise.

Here is the picture translated
[image]

[Here is a page](http://mybikenote.com/bike/5080) that says it's a:

Panasonic B-OCQ 1990
[image]

> A road bike from the good old days when Panasonic was full of challenge.
> The lightest road bike at the time made of carbon monocoque.
> Although it is now a heavy category in terms of weight,
> Creating this shape in this era
> Selling this in this era
> I think it is something we should be proud of as a manufacturer of Japan.

Comment: Thank you so much! What an incredible bike for the time; obscure enough to evade my Google skills. That Y 450.000  sticker price converts to $ 3.000 in 1990's money! No wonder the protagonist carried his bike around. The production company couldn't have afforded a second one.

Comment: @KlausPeter I've ridden a wheel of that design.  It was terrifying when a spoke broke on a descent and the wheel jammed in the frame, and the replacement spoke was 30x what a normal spoke cost.   But it looks so fast !